# TypeError: Cannot read property 'emailTaken' of null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

When I enter my email in my RegisterForm and it's equal to the one that sets ['emailTaken'] to true. I get the following error code:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emailTaken' of null
```

Here is the code of my function:

```
checkEmail(control:FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any>{
    const answer = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(control.value == 'stijn.wauters@outlook.com'){
          resolve({'emailTaken': true})
        }else{
          resolve(null)
        }
      },1500);
    });
    return answer;
  }
```

And here I trigger the ERROR in HTML:

```
<span *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').errors['emailTaken']" class="help-block">
                            Email is already taken!
                        </span>
```

How can I fix this so it doesn't give me errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can check null by ? operator

```
<span *ngIf="registerForm.get('email')?.errors['emailTaken']" class="help-block">
                            Email is already taken!
                        </span>
```

Comment: Angular documentation for this: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: The check should be on `errors` property (`registerForm.get('email').errors?['emailTaken']`). Note that you can use dot notation (`errors.emailTaken`) so when there's no `emailTaken` error you get `undefined` and the `ngIf` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: It doesn't display anything now

Answer (score 1):

[hasError](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasError) can be more useful for checking the errors.

```
<span *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').hasError('emailTaken')" class="help-block">
       Email is already taken!
</span>
```